# Can't redefine sys.stdin in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I try to do this in a jupyter notebook:

```py
import sys
with open('my_file') as f_in:
    sys.stdin = f_in
    my_list = input().split()
    sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__
print(my_list)
```

But it doesn't work: the input instruction wait I give some entry

Comment: Why not just use `my_list = f_in.readlines()`?

Comment: Because I want to test some codes from other people... they are supposed to write classical `input` to get datas and do some stuff...